# VB - Perform calculations and update results when specific value changes

Tags: vb.net

How do I calculate the amount of money one has to pay for my fictive "service" and how do I update the result while the "service-session" keeps going?

I have four `TextBox`es:

- The first (`TextBox1`) contains the start time of the service-session
- The second (`TextBox2`) contains the duration of the session
- The third (`TextBox3`) contains a fix value of `25.36`
- The fourth (`TextBox4`) shall display the result of the calculation

When the sessions duration (value of `TextBox2`) changes, I want to update the result within `TextBox4`. For every hour the session lasts, the fixed value of 25.36 Euro (`TextBox3`) shall be added to the result. How can I achieve that?

Here is what I tried:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Now.ToLongTimeString.ToString()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Dim StartTime As DateTime = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Dim EndTime As DateTime = Now.ToLongTimeString.ToString
        Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = EndTime - StartTime
        Me.TextBox2.Text = (TotalTime).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the milliseconds interval of your timer?

Comment: Thank you Steve .. In my propriete of Timer1 ( 1000 - False ) .. the duration of session appears in TextBox2 like this ( 00:00:00 )

Comment: So you want to calculate the wage seconds by seconds as the timer fires the event Tick?

Comment: Yes I watt to display the amount to be paid according to the duration of the session in TextBox2 .. the duration of the session in TextBox2 is changed as well as amount in TextBox4 also changes until the end of the session

Comment: Then you need to calculate the wage by seconds (3600 second in an hour) and multiply that value for the duration TotalSeconds. Finally assign the result to your fourth textbox. However the very important thing to do here is to go to your project properties and turn on Option Strict. Using string variables like they were datetime or decimal never ends well

Comment: First, turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply record the start and end time, the deduct start from end and you get duration. You do so by getting DateTime.Now

Or if you want to do it with timer simply track seconds (or whatever).

```
Dim Seconds as Integer
Sub TimerTick
    Seconds +=1
End Sub
```

Then multiply duration with payment per time frame.
If you track seconds and have payment in hours then simply do

```
seconds * payment/60/60
```

---

```
Dim StartTime As DateTime
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartTime = DateTime.Now
    Timer1.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = StartTime.ToLongTimeString
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - StartTime
    TextBox2.Text = TotalTime.TotalSeconds.ToString("0")
    Dim Payment As Double = TotalTime.TotalHours * CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    TextBox4.Text = Payment.ToString("C", Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Crule.But i want to calculate the amount to pay not Interval. The interval of duration work very well in TextBox2

Comment: Then multiply duration with payment. If you track seconds, then divide hourly wage with 60 twice (first time to get salary for a minute, a second time for a second)

Comment: Thank you Crule. I am very very beginner for that I could not understand how to insert your code in mine

Comment: It is really simple, multiply your salary with duration, think about it. Where is your salary, where is your duration, then combine those two.

Comment: I have already tried to do it but I have not managed to display the amount in TextBox4 .. like this (     Dim Total_Pay As Double = 0 -
        Total_Pay = CStr(CDbl(TextBox2.Text) * CDbl(TextBox3.Text) / 60) -
        TextBox4.Text = Format(Total_Pay, "#,##0.00")

Comment: it's easier to use declared variables than parse strings. And you can't parse String with Cdbl if it's not ina a proper double (number) format (0,00...) You have to use CDate instead since you are using (24:60:60).

Comment: Now it works very very well .. Thank you very much .. very very nice of you .. one last remark and will be finished to the wonder .. how to make the session duration in TextBox2 for 60 seconds will be displayed like that (00: 01.00) step 61 and when it reaches 60 Minutes will show as this (1:00:00) not 3600

Comment: Inspect properties of your TimeSpan variable, it should become clear.

Comment: Please accept Crule's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.